# Javascript that displays different page every hour needs to open in new window

Tags: javascript, anchor, document, target, timed

I have javascript on my page which opens a different page every hour of the day.  This example uses a text link in the code. It opens in the same window it is displayed on. Works fine except I need it to open the click result in a new window. I'd like to keep it really simple code wise.  I'd also like to use graphics as the link instead of text.

Any suggestions?

```
RightNow = new Date();
document.write("<a href='" + RightNow.getHours() 
  + ".html'>NON PASSKEY ENTRANCE</a>")
```

I've tried numerous ways trying to put a target in the code, and I'll either break it where it will not show on the page at all or it still opens in the parent. Tried calling it as a function too without success.

Comment: Look into `window.open()`

Comment: Adding `target='_blank'` to the anchor should make the link open in a new window. Please show how you tried to do this.

Comment: you probably shouldn't call `document.write()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear, and you seem to be asking for several things. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to ask just one clear, specific question.

Comment: Instead of writing a new anchor each hour, just modify the `href` of an existing link.